# Swapping items in ArrayList

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a method that swaps two items in an ArrayList. As an example I'm trying to make it so that oneList = ["dog", "cat", "mouse", "panda"] and then you do swap(1, 2, oneList) it will end up being ["dog", "mouse", "cat", "panda"]

```
void swap(int a, int b, ArrayList<String> oneList)
{
    oneList.set(a, oneList.get(b)) //puts whatever is in position b into position a
}
```

Comment: You've only done half the swap, ie. moving `b` to `a`.

Answer (score 4):

You can change to either using :

```
String temp = oneList.get(a); 
oneList.set(a, oneList.get(b));
oneList.set(b,temp);
```

Or use `Collections` built-in `swap` method

```
void swap(int a, int b, ArrayList<String> oneList) {
    // do some bounds check
    Collections.swap(oneList, a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a temporary variable to make the swap possible:

```
void swap(int a, int b, ArrayList<String> oneList) {
    // you might also want to check that both a and b fall within the bounds of the list
    String temp = oneList.get(b);
    oneList.set(b, oneList.get(a));
    oneList.set(a, temp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have pointed out, you are only updating the first value in the list (you need to save it first, and then set the second one). Also, you could make the method generic on any type of `List` (please program to the interface). Like,

```
<T> void swap(int a, int b, List<T> oneList) {
    T t = oneList.get(a);
    oneList.set(a, oneList.get(b));
    oneList.set(b, t);
}
```